# Git bash : go to your current working project directory

Tags: git, git-bash

How do we setup an alias in git (.bashrc) to jump to my project working directory.

Say my directory would be->   c:\projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work

```
home() {
    cd /c/projects
}
```